# A family of $8$-regular Ramanujan Cayley Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups

I'm looking for expander graphs with certain properties.

> Is there a family of $8$-regular Ramanujan Cayley graphs $\{\text{Cay}(G_n,S_n)\}_n$ such that each of them has no cycles of odd length?

If you can describe such family without the condition on the cycles, then it may still be useful and I will check the condition on the cycles myself.

Comment: I assume you have seen the PSL2/PGL2 ones?

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I've seen something with $SL_n$. What is the construction with $PSL_2/PGL_2$?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=963118 makes $p+1$-regular Ramnujan Cayley graphs by finding $p+1$ solutions to a sums of squares equals $q$ and lifting them to elements of PGL(2,q) (that generate PSL2 or PGL2)

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1290630 does something similar using polynomials instead of primes, still PGL2 for the group, I believe.

Comment: I'll have a look.

Comment: Starting with this book might be better: http://www2.unine.ch/repository/default/content/sites/math/files/shared/documents/articles/valette22-04-02.pdf